# How to list all the alias for all the user have on my linux box from root

Tags: shell, alias

I have been trying to check the alias the all the user can possible have on my system, I am using root.  There is any command that can list them?

Comment: List the aliases of the root user? Another user? What shell are you using? Is it the default `bash`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: all the aliases that every user could _possibly_ have, or all the aliases that  every user _currently_ has?

Comment: All the aliases that every user currently has. It use default bash. It is Ubuntu server 14.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really possible because aliases only "exist" when the user is logged in.  If their .profile etc login scripts define some aliases, they will have those when they first log in, but they may also `source` other scripts to define more aliases or define them on the command-line.

You can, however, list the aliases that each user will have *at the moment they log in* with something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

for user in $(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1) ; do
    uid=$(getent passwd "$user" | cut -d: -f3)
    if [ "$uid" -ge 1000 ] ; then
        ushell=$(getent passwd "$user" | cut -d: -f7)
        [ -z "$ushell" ] && ushell='/bin/sh'
        echo "aliases for $user:"
        if [[ "$ushell" =~ /s?bin/(true|false|sync|ftponly|nologin) ]] ; then
            :
        elif [[ "$ushell" =~ /s?bin/(t?csh|zsh|s?ash) ]] ; then
            su - "$user" $ushell -c 'alias'
        elif [[ "$ushell" =~ /s?bin/([bd]ash|m?ksh|sh) ]] ; then 
            su - "$user" $ushell -c 'alias -p'
        fi
        echo ; echo
    fi
done
```

Note that this skips all UIDs below 1000 - on debian systems, normal (i.e. non-system) user ids start at 1000.  On some other systems, they start at 500.  adjust to suit your system.

It's possible that some shells may not list aliases when told to execute `alias` without an argument.  All the shells I tested (bash, dash, pdksh, mksh, tcsh, zsh) were OK with it but if you find one that doesn't you'll have to handle that with something like `if [ "$ushell" = "/bin/oddshell" ; then ... fi`